# Hadoop - MultipleOutputs.write - OutofMemory - Java heap space

Tags: java, hadoop, out-of-memory

I am writing a hadoop job which processes many files and creates multiple files from each file. I am using "MultipleOutputs" to write them. It works fine for smaller number of files but i get the following error for large number of files. 
The exception is raised on the MultipleOutputs.write(key, value, outputPath);
I have tried increasing the ulimit and -Xmx but to no avail.

```
2013-01-15 13:44:05,154 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$Packet.<init>(DFSOutputStream.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.writeChunk(DFSOutputStream.java:1423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.writeChecksumChunk(FSOutputSummer.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write1(FSOutputSummer.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:54)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter. writeObject( TextOutputFormat.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter. write(TextOutputFormat.java:99)
    **at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.write( MultipleOutputs.java:386)
    at com.demoapp.collector.MPReducer.reduce(MPReducer.java:298)
    at com.demoapp.collector.MPReducer.reduce(MPReducer.java:28)**
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the number of reduce task from 1 to 8 and increased the values of io.sort.mb to and mapred.task.timeout.

[Details](http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2013/01/hadoop-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space.html)

This link was helpful-
[Cloudera blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work with a large number of files, it's probably because you've hit the max number of files that can be served by a datanode. This can be controlled with a property called `dfs.datanode.max.xcievers` in hdfs-site.xml.

As recommended [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1861), you should bump its value to something that will allow your job to run correctly, they recommend 4096:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I tried to set the property using - Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration(); conf.set("dfs.datanode.max.xcievers", "4096"); And ran the job but it did not make any difference.

Comment: @Harpreet This is a datanode property, you need to put it in hdfs-site.xml and restart your cluster for this to take effect.